# Pass a nested array in deferred.done() callback to the outer scope

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-deferred

I asked a similar question a week ago, but didn't have an actual answer to my problem. That's due to the way I had exposed my problem.

I'm writing a jquery google map plugin so we can do something like this :

```
var my_map = $('#map').plugin();
my_map.addMarker( 'Melbourne, Australia' );
my_map.addMarker( 'New York, USA' );
console.log ( my_map.getMarkers() );  // how to return markers array here ?
```

To add my markers I use google geocode, which converts address into latitude and longitude. Once I get the response I add my markers to the map and store them in an array.

That is all working fine. 
To retrieve my markers array I've done this in the plugin :

```
self.getMarkers = function()
{
    self._deferred.done( function()
    {
        // I need to pass this to the outer scope
        console.log( 'Deferred done :' , self.markers ); 
        return self.markers;
    });
 }
```

If I just return `self.markers` without using `deferred` then the array is empty because the response hasn't been back yet, but if I use `deferred` then I can't pass the array to the outer scope.

Also I don't want the developer using the plugin to have to do this :

```
my_map.done( function( markers ) {
   // code
});
```

I could do that by returning the promise, but I'd like to get the markers array just by doing `my_map.getMarkers()`

I hope the problem is clear, ask me for clarifications if it's not.
If you need to see the full code it's here : http://jsfiddle.net/Vy4da/

Comment: in order to have `my_map.done` would be a lot better to pass array of markers instead of individual `addMarker` so you can track status of array and trigger a callback internally

Comment: @charlietfl that's actually what it is in the original version I'm passing an object of markers to `addMarkers()`, but I simplified the plugin to expose my actual issue, thanks for the advice though :)

Comment: OK..but if you use method `addMarkers` , instead of passing array into initialization object, have no way to know while intializing if markers are being passed in or not

Comment: suggest taking a look at gmap3. Is an awesome wrapper for google maps

Comment: @charlietfl I know gmap3, I'm doing this plugin mostly for learning purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just not how asynchronous code works.  When you call `my_map.getMarkers()` if it makes an asynchronous call you absolutely cannot guarantee when it will complete and be accessible to the code "after" that call.  You have to expose the fact that this is an asynchronous call *somehow*.

The least-exposed way, in my opinion, would be to allow users to provide a callback function that uses the array returned in the following fashion:

```
my_map.getMarkers(function (array) {
    //do stuff with returned array here
});
```

You can bind that callback function to `.done`.  I think you will get more flexibility by returning the promise itself, though.  I suppose you could do both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `getMarkers()` doesn't do an asynchronous call itself, but it needs to wait for `addMarker()` (the one doing the asynchronous call) to be done, so I guess that's the same thing. I think that's a good solution that you gave me here, I was just wondering if I could have a sort of facade so calling `getMarkers()`  will return the markers when they're ready. But I guess not.

Comment: @jerome.s how would you handle the circumstance where `getMarkers` is not ready?  You have no way of knowing when that is

Comment: Yeah there's no way of knowing it, I thought there could be one somehow, that's why I came here and asked the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you have at least 2 more options.

Since `getMarkers()` is really a synchronous call that does data processing on something that's already occurred, you only need to handle the situation with `addMarker()` being asynchronous. And here all you need to do is ensure that you are done adding markers. For example:

```
// For this to work, you need to put return statements at the start of addMarker and
// placeMarker so that they return the promises they are making

$.when(my_map.addMarker("Melbourne"), my_map.addMarker("New York, USA"))
.then(function()
{
   // a synchronous my_map.getMarkers() is safe to use here
   // just return self._Markers.markers;
});
```

As you can see the only difficulty is in parallelizing the `addMarker` events and only using `getMarkers` when they are all done. I recommend making this part of your plugin to ease things for your developers.

```
self.addMarkers = function( /*...*/ ) // accept array of location or comma separated list
{
    var args = [].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    return $.when.apply(null, args.map(self.addMarker, self));
}
```

Usage:

```
my_map.addMarkers('Melbourne, Australia', 'New York, USA')
.then(function()
{
   console.log(my_map.getMarkers()); // works if synchronous
   console.log(my_map._Markers.markers); // also works
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Vy4da/1/

Your second option is to return an *evaluation object* separate from the original *request object* after a request to your `my_map` is made. This is the pattern used by AJAX in Jquery. You pass in  options to `$.ajax`, and then chain it with `done(function(data,status,jqXHR){...})`, where `jqXHR` is an evaluation object that lets you evaluate the result, and `data` is the part you are probably most interested in (jqXHR.responseText). To use the same pattern in your case, `getMarkers()` would not be present on `my_map` at all, but instead be attached to a constructed object resolved by a map request function. This approach prevents developers from erroneously using `getMarkers()` before it's available, because it simply isn't defined except when resolved through the promise.

---

*Original answer* 
*(based on the misunderstanding that getMarkers was asynchronous)*

If `my_map.getMarkers()` is an asynchronous request of any kind, you can't treat it as a synchronous variable assignment.

so: `var a = my_map.getMarkers()` will *never* have the results of an asynchronous call in it.

If you return a promise instead, you grant the caller the option of deciding how to parallelize this call with other asynchronous calls.

`my_map.getMarkers().done( function( markers ) { });` is one of the more elegant solutions to this, since it allows them to write code in a style that shows synchronous-like control logic while still being an asynchronous call. It also allows them to handle error conditions in any way they like.

I know it's annoying at first, but it's just the reality of asynchronous programming.

Comment: If you look at the full code, you'll see that `getMarkers()` is not an asynchronous call. It's meant to retrieve the marker array. The marker array store the markers once they've been placed on the map. Though, everything you've said is true. I've mentioned returning a promise in my question, but I didn't see the value of it. With the way you explained it, now, I kinda think that returning a promise would be the best option, since that will give flexibility to whoever using the plugin.

Comment: @jerome.s Ah! With that you have more options. Updated